# Get last message (either sent/received) in .Net 6 with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-6.0

Requirement: Get last message (either sent/received) in .Net 6 with Entity Framework.

Issue: `.DistinctBy()` is not working with multiple parameters.

```
IQueryable<Chat> query = _context.chats
.Include (x => x.Sender)
.Include (x => x.Receiver)
.DistinctBy(x =>(x.senderId),(x.receiverId))
.OrderByDescending(x => x.id);
```

Comment: Surely you'd just take the chat with the max/orderbydesc time? What has distinct got to do with anything?

Comment: @HasBeanCounter I just trying to remove duplication and get recent/latest one.

Comment: @HasBeanCounter In other words need to select one if one record has receiverId = 2 and senderId = 3. And In other record receiverId=3 and senderId = 2. We have to consider both are same, now we just need to select recent one.  Please suggest code based on your understanding.

Comment: Even if DistinctBy would support multiple parameters, your query would result in a sorted list of chats with the highest senderId or receiverId first. Does that mean that this is the last message? Surely you won't change a SendeId every time a Sender sends a message?

Comment: That's not a distinct, it's just an OR; you want "where((sender==2 && receiver==3) || (sender==3 && receiver==2)), order by chatDate descending, first" (or maxby chatDate etc. ). If youre just after the last message sent/received by one person, you need only their id in the where, viz; "where(sender==2 || receiver==2)"

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework, when using `DistinctBy` to get distinct records based on multiple properties, you should create an anonymous type for the properties you want to include in the distinct comparison. Here's how you can modify your query to achieve this:

```
IQueryable<Chat> query = _context.Chats
    .Include(x => x.Sender)
    .Include(x => x.Receiver)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.SenderId, x.ReceiverId })
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: Error Detail: .Where() is not translated after the your given query.  Actually, I used Where clause to select receiverId or senderId (received from request).

Comment: if so share the query with where() along with the chats , receiver and sender models.